# TemplateDoesNotExist at /account/

Tags: python, django, dynamic-url

I experimented with making my URLs more dynamic, and ended up breaking something. I can figure it out for the life of me! Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only URLs working are my login and logout templates. I get why those are working, but what am I doing wrong for the rest of my URLs?

Here's the traceback I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/xxxxx/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/xxxxx/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/diversely/accounts/views.py", line 20, in home
    return render(request, 'accounts:home')
  File "/xxxxx/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/xxxxx/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/xxxxx/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 25, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts:home
[03/Jun/2017 03:15:17] "GET /account/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78337
```

Here are my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from accounts.forms import (
    RegistrationForm,
    EditProfileForm
)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    UserChangeForm,
    PasswordChangeForm
)
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    name = 'Matthew Zayas'
    args = {'myName': name}
    return render(request, 'accounts:home')

def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts:register', args)

def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'accounts:view_profile', args)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts:edit_profile', args)

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
        else:
            return redirect('accounts:change_password')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts:change_password', args)
```

My URLs:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
        login,
        logout,
        password_reset,
        password_reset_done,
        password_reset_confirm,
        password_reset_complete
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'accounts/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html'}, name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset-password/complete$', password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

Here's my middleware:

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')    
        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if path == reverse('accounts:logout').lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        elif request.user.is_authenticated() or url_is_exempt:
            return None
        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function takes two required argumernts.

From the docs,

> **render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)[source]**
>
> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.
>
> **Required arguments**
>
> **request**
>
> The request object used to generate this response.
>
> **template_name**
>
> The full name of a template to use or sequence of template names. If a sequence is given, the first template that exists will be used. See the [template loading documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#template-loading) for more information on how templates are found.

So, you need to add the **template_name** in the function, not the namespace of the url.

Edit your views,

```
def home(request):
    name = 'Matthew Zayas'
    args = {'myName': name}
    #add the full name of the template and the 
    #context variables you want to add.
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)

def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    #here tooo..
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', args)

def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    #same here..
    return render(request, 'accounts/view_profile.html', args)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
        else:
            return redirect('accounts:change_password')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    #same thing here too
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked the fact that I'd been using the render function and hastily edited all of my URLs to match the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten to include the reverse function in your views.

Your code

```
def home(request):
name = 'Matthew Zayas'
args = {'myName': name}
return render(request, 'accounts:home')
```

Changes to be made is

```
def home(request):
name = 'Matthew Zayas'
args = {'myName': name}
return render(request, reverse('accounts:home'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the same error persist ? or are you getting any new errors?. As per the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/ the reverse function should convert the  template location from 'account:home' to account/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "settings.py" file on your project directory and change the Template 'DIRS':[]

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]